# Ruby on Rails: how do you write a find statement that sums up a bunch of values if an object belongs to another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say Users have BankAccounts which have a balance value.

So, how do I generate an array that Users and the total value of all their BankAccounts' values added together?

Comment: Are you saying a user has many bank_accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you want, but you can do something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select user_id, sum(balance) from accounts group by user_id;")
```

This will give you an array of user_ids and balances from the accounts table.  The advantage of doing it this way is that it comes down to only one SQL query.

Comment: ...and you don't end up retrieving the entire table.  I don't know if that matters to you, but full table retrievals kill one of my apps and have to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: how do I put that into an arary or hash?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like this. I don't believe it's possible to use `#sum` via an association.

```
class User
  def net_worth
    BankAccount.sum(:balance, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", self.id])
  end
end
```

**Edit**

I see a reference to a `#sum` in [AssociationCollection](http://caboo.se/doc/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection.html#M006629), so try this:

```
class User
  def net_worth
    self.bank_accounts.sum(:balance)
  end
end
```

(I haven't tested this code)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the users you want so I'll just assume you want all users.

```
@users = User.all
```

Then you need to take the array and collect it with only the elements you want.

```
@users.collect! {|u| [u.name, u.bank_account_total_value]}
```

For this kinda attribute I would set it in the model assuming you have `has_many :transactions` as an association

```
Class User

 has_many :transactions 

 def bank_account_total_value
     total = 0
     self.transactions.each do |t|
        total += t.amount
     end 
 end   

end
```

Comment: It may be okay for this example (how many bank accounts will a person realistically have?) but in general it's a super bad idea to do calculations like this in Ruby code when you could do it in SQL.